# How to check if the service broker is enabled at the server level and whether it is being utilized?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

The following query return 1 for is_broker_enabled for a couple of databases. However, I don't recollect ever using the service broker feature.

```
SELECT db.database_id, db.[name] AS [Database Name], is_broker_enabled
FROM sys.databases AS db
```

How to check if the service broker is enabled at the server level and whether it is being utilized?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Service Broker is a server level feature, rather it's individually enabled at the database level.

For more information on managing it, including turning it off, please see [Managing Service Broker Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/service-broker/managing-service-broker-applications?view=sql-server-ver15). Or for general information, please read the [Books Online for Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Is there any way to check whether this is utilized?